# collecting tweets using tweepy cursor

Tags: file, csv, tweets

I want to collect tweets (in python dictionary format) containing some key words into a csv file. I have used tweepy cursor. But it returns nothing.

Following the answer in "[Managing Tweepy API Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469713/managing-tweepy-api-search)" I have tried to collect tweets using cursor. But the code stops after some seconds, with out returning any message.

```
import TwitterCredentials
import tweepy
import csv
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
import json

def authenticate():
    auth=OAuthHandler(TwitterCredentials.consumerKey, 
    TwitterCredentials.consumerSecretKey)
    auth.set_access_token(TwitterCredentials.accessToken,
    TwitterCredentials.accessTokenSecret)
    api=tweepy.API(auth)

    return api

def collectTweet(api, query, max_tweets):
    i=1
    for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets):
        loadCsvFile(json.loads(tweet))
        print(str(i)+ " ")
        i+=1


def loadCsvFile(tweet): 
    csv_file.writerow([tweet['id'],tweet['created_at'],tweet['text'],
    tweet['retweet_count'],tweet['source']])



if __name__ == '__main__':

    query=['air pollution', 'PM 2.5']
    max_tweets=500

    f=open('collected_tweets.csv', 'w')
    csv_file=csv.writer(f)
    csv_file.writerow(['id','created_at','text',
    'retweet_count','source'])

    api=authenticate()
    collectTweet(api, query, max_tweets)
```

I want to get the messages in dictionary format such that the id, created_at, text, source information can be extracted from it.

This code didn't return any error and didn't return any message also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the tweepy.cursor returns status where _json is the dict where all the field of a tweet are present. so the code should be

```
for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, lang='en').items(max_tweets):
           loadCsvFile(status._json)
```

...
Then it worked.