# Extracting tweets using Python and Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to look at President Trump's tweets on immigration and do some sentiment analysis on it. My code is:

```
import pprint
import datetime

# startDate = datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 20, 0, 0, 0)

# endDate = datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 29, 0, 0, 0)

username = "realDonaldTrump"

page = 1
stop_loop = False

finalList1 = []

curs = tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=username)

for item in curs.items():
    finalList1.append(item)

print(len(finalList1))
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in finalList1], columns=['Tweets'])

#Add Relevant data

data['len']  = np.array([len(tweet.text) for tweet in finalList1])
data['ID']   = np.array([tweet.id for tweet in finalList1])
data['Date'] = np.array([tweet.created_at for tweet in finalList1])
data['Source'] = np.array([tweet.source for tweet in finalList1])
data['Likes']  = np.array([tweet.favorite_count for tweet in finalList1])
data['RTs']    = np.array([tweet.retweet_count for tweet in finalList1])

#Sentiment Analysis
from textblob import TextBlob
import re

def clean_tweet(tweet):
    '''
    Utility function to clean the text in a tweet by removing 
    links and special characters using regex.
    '''
    return ' '.join(re.sub("(@[A-Za-z0-9]+)|([^0-9A-Za-z \t])|(\w+:\/\/\S+)", " ", tweet).split())

def analize_sentiment(tweet):
    '''
    Utility function to classify the polarity of a tweet
    using textblob.
    '''
    analysis = TextBlob(clean_tweet(tweet))
    if analysis.sentiment.polarity > 0:
        return 1
    elif analysis.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return -1

data['SA'] = np.array([ analize_sentiment(tweet) for tweet in data['Tweets'] ])
```

The code works perfectly fine. However, I have 2 questions:

1. How do I get access to tweets before these? It gives me 3200 tweets; how do I get the ones before that
2. How do I get the Donald Trump's tweets which have specific keywords like 'immigration', 'refugee', 'china' etc.

I have been trying to figure out a way but unsuccessful.

Answer (score 0):

for searching for a specific keywords you can use

[API.search][1]

for example:

```
q="immigration"
searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets)]
```

> [1]: http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html   [2]:
>   [Managing Tweepy API Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469713/managing-tweepy-api-search)

Comment: but it gives all the tweets in the twitter feed. I need the ones specifically tweeted by some specific user like realDonaldTrump. Is there a way to do that?