# How to unpack JSON provided by tweepy

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

I scraped tweets using tweepy using code based on first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469713/managing-tweepy-api-search), which is as following

```
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth,wait_on_rate_limit=True)

query = 'kubernetes'
max_tweets = 200
searched_tweets = []
last_id = -1
while len(searched_tweets) < max_tweets:
    count = max_tweets - len(searched_tweets)
    try:
        new_tweets = api.search(q=query, count=count, max_id=str(last_id - 1))
        if not new_tweets:
            break
        searched_tweets.extend(new_tweets)
        last_id = new_tweets[-1].id
    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        break
```

It provides a list of json objects such as `searched_tweets[2]`
output (truncated)

```
Status(_api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0x7fc13dbab828>, _json={'created_at': 'Wed Jun 10 14:06:51 +0000 2020', 'id': 1270719075388280834, 'id_str': '1270719075388280834', 'text': "RT @CDWGWAGov: According to @IBM's new CEO, #hybridcloud &amp; #AI are the two dominant forces driving #digitaltransformation #Kubernetes #IoT…", 'truncated': False,
```

I need creation date and tweet text so I used following code to extract them

```
for tweet in searched_tweets:
  new_tweet = json.dumps(tweet)
  dct = json.loads(new_tweet._json)
  created_at=dct['created_at']
  txt=dct['text']
```

but it is giving

```
TypeError: Object of type 'Status' is not JSON serializable
```

I have tried [this](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/1102) solution to solve this error which is `api = tweepy.API(auth, parser=tweepy.parsers.JSONParser())` it give `KeyError: -1`
I have tried almost every other solution on stackoverflow but nothing worked for me. Can someone help me to unpack json and get those two values? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Status` object of tweepy itself is not JSON serializable, but it has a `_json` property can be JSON serialized

For example

```
status_list = api.user_timeline(user_handler)
status = status_list[0]
json_str = json.dumps(status._json)
```

I suspect the error is caused by this line
`new_tweet = json.dumps(tweet)` here, so simply call the `_json` property on this line

```
new_tweet = json.dumps(tweet._json)
```

and modify the relevant follow on code. This should solve your problem